# add controller to a angular-tiny template

Tags: angularjs, tinymce

I'm trying to use tinyMCE in my angualar app. I'm using the directive provided by angular-ui-tinymce module. I have a state in wich i put the textarea and i want to buitd some templates that the user can choice. Moreover, I want to make dynamic these template. Here is my controller :

```
(function(){
 'use strict';
  angular
  .module('app.core')
      .controller('refertazioneController', refertazioneController);

 function refertazioneController($stateParams){
   var vm = this;
   vm.prova="refertazioneController";
   vm.tinymceModel = '';
   vm.sospeso=true;
   vm.params = $stateParams;
   vm.currentUser = sessionStorage;
   vm.tinymceOptions = {

  inline: false,
  slector: 'textarea',

  height: 500,
  plugins : 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview template save',
  skin: 'lightgray',
  theme : 'modern',
  language:'it',
  statusbar: false,
  templates:[ {title: 'Titolo1', description: 'Descrizione1', url: 'sections/refertazione/referto1.html'},
              {title: 'Titolo2', description: 'Secondo referto', url: 'sections/refertazione/referto1.html'}
            ]
};
}
})();
```

and this is the template:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
 <strong>A.S.L. 02 LANCIANO-VASTO-CHIETI</strong>
</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
 <strong>Ospedale Clinicizzato "SS.Annunziata"</strong>
</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
 <strong>Servizio Radiologia</strong>
</p>
 <p style="text-align: center;">
  <strong>Sezione di Scienze Radiologiche&nbsp;dell Universit&agrave;        </strong>
</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Direttore: Prof. Antonio Raffaele    Cotroneo</p>
```

the problem is that I can not use my controller in the template. I tryed to handle the template like a state in ui router but the same. Can someone suggest me an approach?

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't this work?

```
<div ng-controller="refertazioneController as referCtrl">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
     <strong>A.S.L. 02 LANCIANO-VASTO-CHIETI</strong>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
     <strong>Ospedale Clinicizzato "SS.Annunziata"</strong>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
     <strong>Servizio Radiologia</strong>
    </p>
     <p style="text-align: center;">
      <strong>Sezione di Scienze Radiologiche&nbsp;dell Universit&agrave;        </strong>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">Direttore: Prof. Antonio Raffaele    Cotroneo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this approach would work because my controller already has his template in wich I have the tiny text area in wich I load the template

Comment: this solution not works. seems impossible add a controllor to a template